# The Hessian and Eigenvalues

Tags: real-analysis

i am wondering if it is necessary to find the eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix in dimensions > 2 when we are looking for the extrema of a function in the case that one wants to resolve this problem through the way of considering the definitiness of the Hessian.

In other words how do i prove if the Hessian is negative definite if i wouldn't like to go through the eigenvalue problem ?

Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is [Sylvester's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion): a Hermitian (and hence symmetric, which is sufficient for the Hessian) matrix
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & \cdots \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix} $$
is positive-definite if and only if the determinants of the principal minors,
$$ a_{11}, \begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{vmatrix}, \begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{vmatrix}, \dotsc  $$
are all positive. This is obviously much easier to calculate than doing all the eigenvalues.

(See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811387/characterization-of-positive-definite-matrix-with-principal-minors) for a simpler proof than Wikipedia's)