# Counterexample to Sylvester's criterion for non-hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Sylvester's criterion is stated and proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811387/characterization-of-positive-definite-matrix-with-principal-minors). I was wondering: why is it stated only for Hermitian matrix? If $A$ is not hermitian, does it hold for A? If not, which implication(s) fail and can you provide a counterexample? And if not, is there any adjustment to be made to the proof to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -100 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Indeed, for $(1,0)*A*(1,0)^T=1-100=-99$, yet the minors are positive.