# Proof of Sylvester's criterion for Hermitian matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Can anyone provide a proof of [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion) for positive definiteness **for Hermitian matrices**? All I can find is [this proof](https://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/sylvesters-criterion-for-positive-definiteness) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion), both about real symmetric matrices.

Comment: All those proofs work for Hermitian matrices if you replace $T$ with $*$ whenever it's appropriate

Comment: Check this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811387/characterization-of-positive-definite-matrix-with-principal-minors