# Any simpler proof of Sylvester’s criterion for positive-semidefinite matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have seem one proof [here](https://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/sylvesters-criterion-for-positive-semidefinite-matrices-ii/). However it involves concepts like exterior algebra. For positive definite matrix there is a proof for Sylvester's criterion by [induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811387/characterization-of-positive-definite-matrix-with-principal-minors). I am wondering if there is any simpler proof for positive semi-definite matrix. Thanks!