# Positive definite matrix over a non-Archimedean field

Tags: matrices, field-theory, positive-definite, infinitesimals

Suppose $K$ is a non-Archimedean ordered field, and $A$ is an $n\times n$ square matrix over $K$ such that (1) all diagonal entries of $A$ are $1$, and (2) all off-diagonal entries of $A$ are infinitesimal (i.e. between $-\frac1k$ and $\frac1k$ for all nonzero natural numbers $k$).  For instance, if $K=\mathbb{R}(x)$ is the field of rational functions, ordered with $x$ infinitesimal, then the off-diagonal entries of $A$ could be polynomials in $x$ with zero constant term.

Does it follow that $A$ is positive definite, i.e. that $V^{T} A V > 0$ (in the ordering of $K$) for all nonzero $V\in K^n$?  This seems intuitive to me because it is an "infinitesimal deformation of the identity matrix", but I don't immediately see how to prove it.

Comment: So the ordering is $f(x) \ge g(x)$ if there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $0 < |a| < \epsilon \implies f(a) \ge g(a)$ ?

Comment: @reuns The ordering on $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is defined by saying that the sign of a polynomial is the sign of its first (i.e. with smallest exponent) nonzero coefficient, and the sign of a rational function is defined by the usual rule of signs for division.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following statement is valid over $\mathbb{R}$: if $(a_{ij})$ is symmetric and $a_{ii} > \sum_{j\ne i} |a_{ij}|$ for all $i$, then $(a_{ij})$ is positive definite. Now, if we have an "algebraic" statement valid over $\mathbb{R}$, it will be valid over any "real closed field". That statement is $\langle A x, x\rangle > 0$ for all $x \ne 0$. But your ordered field can be imbedded in a real closed field, so the statement is therefore true over any ordered field.

This is the philosophy... But probably the statement can be proved directly, without all this "meta" stuff..

$\bf{Added:}$ The dominant diagonal element criterion is sharp, as one can see looking at the eigenvalues of the matrix $(a_{ij}) = (1_{ij})$. But a  weaker condition is enough, for instance $|a_{ij}|< \frac{1}{n-1}$ for all $i\ne j$. It is enough to add up all the inequalities:
$$\frac{1}{n-1}\left (x^2_{i} + x^2_{j}\right) + 2 a_{ij} x_i x_j\ge 0$$ for $i<j$, and note that the inequalities are strict for non-zero variables.

$\bf{Added 2:}$. In fact diagonal dominant implies positive is quite simple. Just add all the inequalities;
$$ |a_{ij}| x_{i}^2 + |a_{ij}| x_{j}^2+ 2 a_{ij} x_i x_j\ge 0$$ for all $i< j$ and get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n s_i x^2_i + \sum_{i<j} 2 a_{ij} x_i x_j\ge 0$$ where 
$$s_i = \sum_{j\ne i} |a_{ij}|$$

$\bf{Added 3:}$ Let's also give a purely algebraic proof  that diagonal dominant matrix ( by rows, $a_{ii} > \sum_{j\ne i} |a_{ij}|$ for all $i$) have determinant $>0$.

1. The determinant cannot be $0$. Otherwise the system $A x = 0$ would have a non-zero solution. Get a contradiction, by considering the largest 
   $|x_i|$.
2. Deform the matrix to a matrix with positive determinant, while preserving dominance. The usual proof uses the intermediate value property for polynomials. We'll only use that property for polynomials of degree $1$, valid for every ordered field.

For this, consider for $t\in [0,1]$ the matrix $A_t$ that differs from $A$ only on first row, which is $(a_{11}, t a_{12}, \ldots, t a_{1n})$. We have 
$$\det A_t = (1-t) a_{11} \det A' + t \det A$$ where $\det A'$ is the determinant of the matrix $(a_{ij})_{2 \le i,j\le n}$. So we can do an induction argument. $n=1$ case is trivial. Assume true for $n-1$. Then we have $\det A'>0$. Therefore, $\det A_0 >0$. We know that $\det A_t \ne 0$ for $t \in [0,1]$ ( determinant of a dominant matrix). We conclude $\det A_t >0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, and in particular, $\det A_1 = \det A >0$.

Comment: The proof of "strictly diagonally dominant => positive definite" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix#Applications_and_properties essentially reduces it to Sylvester's criterion, which is what @Chappers used in his answer.  So if is his answer works over any ordered field, then so should yours directly without appeal to the meta stuff; right?

Comment: @Mike Shulman: The proof for $\mathbb{R}$ uses the fact that the matrix $D + t N$ is non-singular for $t\in [0,1]$ ( this works easily for every field)  so the determinant has constant sign. The last  "so" works apriori only for $\mathbb{R}$, not for every ordered field.

Comment: @Mike Shulman: However, the weaker dominant diagonal result is much easier, and seems enough in your case.

Comment: @Mike Shulman: One would want to see an algebraic  proof for the positivity of the determinant if $a_{ij} > \sum_{j \ne i} |a_{ij}|$, right ? ( the matrix not necessarily symmetric).

Comment: I don't understand, what is the "weaker" result you refer to?

Comment: In my examples the matrices are usually symmetric, so if the result is easier in that case I'd be interested to know it, but in principle I'd like to know the answer for the non-symmetric case too.

Comment: @Mike Shulman: OK, so the dominant implies positive definite is also simple. Perhaps so positive determinant fact ( non-symmetric case) is a bit more involved.

Comment: I don't understand your addition 2, can you please give more details?

Comment: @Mike Shulman: I corrected some typos and added some details

Comment: Got it, thanks!  Do you have anything to say about the non-symmetric case?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the matrix is symmetric (since only the symmetric part survives in $v^TAv$), one can apply [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion), using e.g. the Laplace expansion and induction: $1$, the first minor, is positive-definite. Supposing the $k$th is positive-definite and can be written as $1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal, then the Laplace expansion on the $k+1$ row (or column) of the $(k+1)$st minor gives an expression of the form
$$ \det{A_k} = 1(1+\epsilon) + \epsilon' = 1+\epsilon'', $$
where the $\epsilon$s are all infinitesimal, since every element of the row apart from the last $1$ contains an infinitesimal.

Comment: That's nice.  Is it obvious that Sylvester's criterion works over any ordered field?

Comment: Provided you can extend it to an ordered field including the eigenvalues, proofs like https://math.stackexchange.com/a/814690/221811 should continue to work. (I don't know of a proof that doesn't use the eigenvalues, although there probably is one.)

Comment: ok.  What do you mean by "only the symmetric part survives"?  Does the "symmetric part" automatically inherit the same assumptions about the diagonal and off-diagonal?

Comment: Of course: provided the field doesn't have characteristic 2, the symmetric part is $(A+A^T)/2$. Diagonal elements come from diagonal ones, off-diagonal are sums of two infinitesimals.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can extend the criterion $v^T A v > 0$ to function fields this way :

Let $K = \mathbb{R}(x)$. For some $A \in K^{n \times n}$, let $D$ be the diagonal matrix of roots of $\det(A-t I) \in K[t]$. Then each $D_{i,i}$ is in the algebraic closure  $\overline{K}$. Let $L = K(D_{1,1} ,\ldots, D_{n,n})$.

The ordering on $K$ is $f \ge g$ if there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall |c| \in (0, \epsilon), f(c) \ge g(c)$.

Thus $\forall v \in K^n, v^T Av > 0$ implies $A(c)$ is positive definite for $|c| \in (0, \epsilon)$ and hence $A(c) = P(c) D(c) P(c)^T$ and $D(c) > 0$, where the columns of $P(c)$ are some eigenvectors of $A(c)$.

Assuming the  $D_{i,i}$ are distinct it is clear $ (A-D_{i,i} I)P_i = 0$ is a linear equation so that $P \in L^{n \times n}$. If the $D_{i,i}$ are are not distinct then $P \in L^{n \times n}$ stays true.

Finally $A(c) =P(c) D(c) P(c)^T$ on an interval implies (by analytic continuation) $A = P D P^T$ in $L$

(where $D(c) > 0$ only for $|c| \in (0,\epsilon)$, what about $D(c)$ for other $c$ ? Also does $D > 0$ make sense, ie. **is $L$ ordered** ?)

Comment: $K=\mathbb{R}(x)$ was just an example; the question is about arbitrary ordered fields $K$.

Comment: @MikeShulman Then you'll probably want to use some basic classification of ordered fields ?

Comment: why?  There ought to be a proof that works for any ordered field without needing to classify it.

Comment: @MikeShulman I meant to use the same argument as in my answer (analytic continuation)

Comment: But your argument "evaluates" elements of $K$ at real numbers, so it doesn't work for an arbitrary field $K$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to use infinitesimals to make a simple argument. To fix a scale, note that it suffices to prove $V^T A V > 0$ just for those vectors $V$ whose largest component (by absolute value) is $1$.

Let $R$ be the subring  of finite numbers and $M$ the (maximal) ideal of infinitesimal numbers. Note that all matrices and vectors involved have components in $R$.

Define $E = A - I$. Then,

$$ V^T A V = V^T V + (V^T E V) \equiv V^T V \pmod M $$

Since $V^T V \geq 1$, we conclude $V^T A V$ is positive.

Comment: I should have thought of that.