# Matrix congruence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In the answer of to the question   [Characterization of positive definite matrix with principal minors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811387/characterization-of-positive-definite-matrix-with-principal-minors#)  I saw such assertion: $Ak=LkDkL∗k \implies Ak$ is congruent to Dk . Tell me please,  why is it right?  Matrices are similar when $A=LDL^-1$, not $L*$, isn't it? 
And,  regarding to another answer,  why "if hermitian matrix A is not positive definite, it must possess at least two(???) negative eigenvalues"? Why not only 1? It has some connection with complex field?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Matrices $A$ and $B$ are **congruent** if $B = P A P^*$ for some invertible matrix $P$ (often $P^*$ in this definition is replaced with $P^{\top}$; the two definitions coincide for real matrices). Matrices $A$ and $B$ are **similar** if $B = P A P^{-1}$ for some $P$. The second claim is not true; it fails for the zero matrix, which is Hermitian and not positive definite.