# Cholesky decomposition how to prove

Tags: cholesky-decomposition

From calculation of the Cholesky decomposition of covariance matrix, prove whether a symmetric matrix being positive or not can be determined from signs of principal diagonal minors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Characterization of positive definite matrix with principal minors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/811387/characterization-of-positive-definite-matrix-with-principal-minors)

Comment: I don't understand, there is no proof that if the signs of principal diagonal minors are positive, the matrix is positive.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding somewhere. Either "positive" is meant as "(semi) definite-positive" (which is the case for a covariance matrix) or "with all its entries $\ge 0$" which is not the case for a covariance matrix in general. The second meaning is out of order here (Cholesky factorization for example is for positive-definite matrices).

Comment: Besides, have you been working on this homework ? Where are you blocked ?

Answer (score 0):

The Cholesky decomposition
$$
C=LL^\top\,,\quad\text{ where }\quad L=\begin{pmatrix}l_{11}&0&\dots&\dots&0\\l_{21}&l_{22}&0&\dots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
l_{n-1,1}&l_{n-1,2}&\dots&\dots&0\\
l_{n1}&l_{n2}&\dots&\dots&l_{nn}\end{pmatrix}
$$
of a symmetric real matrix $C$ exists if and only if $C$ is positive semi-definite.

IMO, the properly formulated question is therefore: Given that $C$ is positive semi-definite how can we use $L$ to determine wheter $C$ is *strictly* positive definite ?

Using $\det(AB)=\det A\det B$ where $A$ is any left upper submatrix of $L$ (aka principal minor) and $B=A^\top$ we find that the principal minors of $C$ are
$$
\det C_1=l_{11}^2\,,\quad\det C_2=(l_{11}l_{22})^2\,,\dots, \det C=(l_{11}\dots l_{nn})^2\,.
$$
By [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)
if $C$ were only symmetric the strict positivity of these determinants
would be a necessary and sufficient criterion for $C$ to be strictly positive definite.

This is obviously the case if and only if none of the $l_{ii}$ is zero.

- Note that only the full determinant
  $$
  \det C=(l_{11}\dots l_{nn})^2
  $$
  needs to be strictly greater zero. In other words, Sylvester's criterion is not needed in full generality since we assume that the eigenvalues of $C$ are nonnegative from the beginning.