# A question on the diagonal element of Cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra

A is symmetric positive definite. So A = TT', where T is lower triangular matrix whose diagonal elements are all strictly positive. Someone told me which I don't understand:

One way to express $t_{ii}^2$ is from the ith leading principal matrix of A, which is

$$
\mathbf{A}_{ii} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
 \mathbf{A}_{i-1, i-1} & \mathbf{a}_{i, 1} \\ \mathbf{a'}_{i, 1} & a_{ii}
\end{array}
\right],
$$

$t_{ii}^2 = a_{ii} - \mathbf{a'}_{i, 1} \mathbf{A^{-1}}_{i-1, i-1} \mathbf{a}_{i, 1}$ for i=2,...,n. And $t_{11}^2 = a_{11}$

Comment: In the [Cholesky-Banachiewicz-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky%E2%80%93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky%E2%80%93Crout_algorithms) that I have been using for almost thirty years now we never have to invert parts of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$. It is much simpler.

Comment: @KurtG. I should have added more background of this question. I need the step to prove  that given a symmetric positive definite matrix A, the determinant of A is less than or equal to the product of $a_{ii}$.

Comment: $\det\big(A\big)\leq \prod_{k=1}^n a_{k,k}$  by Hadamard's Determinant Inequality

Answer (score 0):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4544116/949989) I show that the determinant of $\mathbf{A}$ equals (in your notation)
$$\tag{1}
\operatorname{det}\mathbf{A}=t_{11}^2...t_{nn}^2
$$
(which is not that hard to see when we use $\operatorname{det}\mathbf{A}=\operatorname{det}\mathbf{T}\operatorname{det}\mathbf{T}'=(\operatorname{det}\mathbf{T})^2\,$).

From the [Cholesky-Banachiewicz-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky%E2%80%93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky%E2%80%93Crout_algorithms) we know that
$$
t_{ii}^2=a_{ii}-\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}(T_{ik})^2\le a_{ii}\,.
$$
Therefore, by (1),
$$
\operatorname{det}\mathbf{A}\le a_{11}...a_{nn}\,.
$$

Comment: @Jackie Was this answer helpful ?